# getElementsByTagName() returns 0 results for custom tags

Tags: javascript, dom, tags

I'm trying to get all elements from a custom tag eg. `<bring-home></bring-home>`

Eg. `var elm = document.getElementsByTagName('bring-home'), i;`

```
console.log("Number of Elements: "+elm.length);
```

The above returns 0, and I've only just figured out that this is causing other issues in my code. Is there some reason my custom tags aren't being picked up by this function? How to fix?

Comment: Write HTML instead of making up your own elements.

Comment: Works just fine for me -> **http://jsfiddle.net/T4nkF/**, but why would you do such a thing? Would you be any chance be using an older version of IE ?

Comment: I'm using FF 36.0 latest. I've tried in Chrome (although I have no idea what version that is).

Comment: So, i'm trying to add event listeners only to a certain type of tag (click). The custom tags are designed to be custom elemetns, however i'm still learning. Is it possible i need to use document.regsiterElement() or something?

Comment: I have a partial fix. After seeing adeno's code in JSfiddle, I realized that the function was being called too early. So i called it from onLoad instead of in the header. Now It registers the elements. WIll update if it solves overall problem. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Ok,

1. Script was returning 0 Elements because it was loading in header instead of after page had loaded.

   - to Fix this I simply bundled the `document.getElementsByTagName` function and loaded it in the `<body onload="funcName();">` html.
2. I was still having trouble with a script (not mentioned above) that was to `element.addEventListener('click', function()...)`

   - which was rectified by passing (this) to the function to refer to the object. (might be relevant to another user)...

Thanks for your help to solve.